# Trying to run nx.dev e2e tests I get the error "Cannot find module 'cypress/package.json'"

Tags: angular, cypress, nrwl-nx, nx.dev

I was trying to setup and run nx tests for an established nx.dev angular application.

When I run `nx e2e app-name-e2e`

I get the error:

```
Cannot find module 'cypress/package.json'
Require stack:
- C:\repos\MyConnect2\src\Frontend\myconnect2\node_modules\@nrwl\cypress\src\utils\cypress-version.js
- C:\repos\MyConnect2\src\Frontend\myconnect2\node_modules\@nrwl\cypress\src\executors\cypress\cypress.impl.js
- C:\repos\MyConnect2\src\Frontend\myconnect2\node_modules\@nrwl\tao\src\shared\workspace.js
- C:\repos\MyConnect2\src\Frontend\myconnect2\node_modules\@nrwl\tao\src\commands\run.js
- C:\repos\MyConnect2\src\Frontend\myconnect2\node_modules\@nrwl\tao\index.js
- C:\repos\MyConnect2\src\Frontend\myconnect2\node_modules\@nrwl\cli\lib\run-cli.js
```

e2e tests were never used on this app, so configuration errors are not excluded (as the app had a few upgrades along the way, and e2e config might not have been maintained correctly).

This is running with angular v11.2 (and nx v 11.2), configured with default cypress for this nx.dev version

Comment: Did you install relevant npm dependencies

Comment: yes, dependencies seem to be ok. The remainder of the app works fine. only the default e2e project was never given attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it... Thank you Pali for the comment

As the error states, the module `cypress/package.json` is missing, that means the package "cypress" is missing.

Someone removed it along the way in this project as it takes a while to install...

The package "@nrwl/cypress" (nx.dev's cypress module) does not have a nominated dependency on the "cypress" package (but clearly has an implicit one).

I added the "cypress" package to the package.json file and installed it, and the problem no longer happens

Comment: Yes best practice , whenever you got error like `cannot find module ..... `. try to delete  lock file and node_modules folder and install again.